# disply two rows from single row

Tags: sql

This is the given table:

[image]

I need to get this data without creating temporary table based on the above table:

[image]

We can't use temporary table. I need to display the data with sql query only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT company name,'No' as value, clicks  as data
from table1
union all
SELECT company,'Yes', (clicks - impression)
from table1
order by name,val
```

Comment: how do i sort them ??

Comment: SELECT A.NAME, A.VAL, A.DATA FROM
(SELECT COMPANY AS NAME, 'YES' AS VAL, (CLICKS-IMPRESSIONS) AS DATA
FROM OR_TABLE
UNION
SELECT COMPANY AS NAME, 'NO' AS VAL, IMPRESSIONS AS DATA
FROM OR_TABLE) A
ORDER BY A.NAME ASC;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to unpivot your table:

```
SELECT
    company,
    'No' AS val,
    impression AS data
FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT
    company,
    'Yes' AS val,
    clicks - impression AS data
FROM tbl
ORDER BY company, val
```

Answer (score 0):

You need UNION ALL

```
SELECT company,'No' val, impression as data from your_table
union all
SELECT company,'Yes' val, clicks-impression as data from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select company as name, 'No' as val, impression as data
from tbl
union
select company as name, 'Yes' as val, clicks - impression as data
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COMPANY AS NAME, 'YES' AS VAL, (CLICKS-IMPRESSIONS) AS DATA
FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE
UNION
SELECT COMPANY AS NAME, 'NO' AS VAL, IMPRESSIONS AS DATA
FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE
```

If you want them sorted: Try this:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.VAL, A.DATA FROM
(SELECT COMPANY AS NAME, 'YES' AS VAL, (CLICKS-IMPRESSIONS) AS DATA
FROM OR_TABLE
UNION
SELECT COMPANY AS NAME, 'NO' AS VAL, IMPRESSIONS AS DATA
FROM OR_TABLE) A
ORDER BY A.NAME ASC;
```